# clear datagridview duplicate rows and keep unique rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

so when filling my datagridview I normally do something like

```
    public void FillTable(CoBRAMetaField[] metaFields)
    {
        dataGridView.Rows.Clear();

        // do something with metaFields
    }
```

**Important:**

- `CoBRAMetaField` is a object with a ID and other stuff
- Each row in the grid holds a metafield object

My grid gets filled correctly (sorry, the language is german)

[image]

When I fill the grid another time I only want to remove the rows with metaFields that don't exist in the new metaFields array. I want this behaviour because when a user selected a value for this row I don't want it to get removed and created again because then the selected value is removed too.

I came up with this

```
    public void FillTable(CoBRAMetaField[] metaFields)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++) // loop through the grid rows
        {
            double metaFieldID = (dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Tag as CoBRAMetaField).ID; // get the ID from the row metaField

            if (metaFields.Any(field => field.ID == metaFieldID)) // Does it exist?
                metaFields = metaFields.Where(field => field.ID != metaFieldID).ToArray(); // Remove it from the new array
            else // it doesn't exist
                dataGridView.Rows.Remove(dataGridView.Rows[i]); // remove the row
        }

        // Fill the grid with the remaining metaFields
    }
```

The first run gets initialized correctly

[image]

the second run seems to crash, some fields remain empty

[image]

when I press the button on this row I get a nullpointer exception. I only get this error when using the "new code" so am I missing something? Is there something I didn't think about?

---

**I will provide a full example here**

At first create a `DataGridView` and `Button` on the form. Create a file for all required classes and take this snippet

https://pastebin.com/BFmr2ps9

After that fill the forms code with some test data

https://pastebin.com/Yz84Akkj

and now setup the `DataGridView` logic

https://pastebin.com/qH6kZKZv

I added

```
dataGridView.AllowDrop = false;
dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
dataGridView.AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
```

if you just want to copy paste but you can also do it by the forms designer. Have a look at `dataGridView.Rows.Clear();` this provides a working example. **Comment it out and use the code above to test the incorrect example**

Comment: Link you gave is empty.

Comment: okay this is weird, I updated it

Comment: There is a lot missing from the posted/linked code. There are no definitions for the following variables… `CoBRAMetaField[]`, `ReleaseSetUpData` and `FieldName`… Without these definitions, finding help may be scarce. In addition, there is a link to some code that does not appear to be used anywhere. Where is the `MetaFieldTable` class used? Your comment… _”I will provide a full example here but I don't think it's needed”_ … I think it is needed.

Comment: @JohnG I'm sorry. Now you can take a full working example if someone wants to try to reproduce the project.

Comment: _When I fill the grid another time I only want to remove the rows with metaFields that don't exist in the new metaFields array._ - So why you not simply clear the rows and add all rows from the new array?

Comment: Do you mean that rows already in `DataGridView` shouldn't not be replaced with rows with same Id from the new array?

Comment: because each row holds selected data from the context menu, when I clear it it's gone. when keeping it, the user doesn't has to select it again

Comment: yes, if there are metafields that already exist I don't need to recreate them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is in the code for adding rows (taken from the link):

```
// Fill the grid with the remaining metaFields
for (int i = 0; i < metaFields.Length; i++)
{
    MetaField currentMetaField = metaFields[i];

    dataGridView.Rows.Add(currentMetaField.Name, null);

    DataGridViewRow newRow = dataGridView.Rows[i]; // <-- Problem!

    DataGridViewCell metaFieldCell = newRow.Cells[0];
    metaFieldCell.Tag = currentMetaField;

    (newRow.Cells[1] as DataGridViewAllocationCell).Initialize(releaseSetupData);
}
```

In the marked line you are assuming that the index of the added row is the same as `i`, which is true when you start with empty grid, bit not when the grid is updated and some old records are kept.

The proper way of handling it is to not assume the new row index - it is returned by the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRowCollection_Add_System_Object___) method:

```
int rowIndex = dataGridView.Rows.Add(currentMetaField.Name, null);

DataGridViewRow newRow = dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex];
```

This will solve the original issue from the question.

There is also a problem in the remove part of the code - the `for` loop will miss checking the rows next to the removed ones. Anytime you want to iterate some list and remove items during the iteration, use *reverse* `for` loop and `RemoveAt`:

```
for (int i = dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) // <--
{
    double metaFieldID = (dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Tag as MetaField).ID;

    if (metaFields.Any(field => field.ID == metaFieldID))
        metaFields = metaFields.Where(field => field.ID != metaFieldID).ToArray();
    else
        dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i); // <--
}
```

The removal code could further be improved (currently looks inefficient with these `Any`, `Where` + `ToArray`), but at least with the above changes it will work correctly.

Comment: Exactly what I needed